# How to trigger UIControlEventTouchCancel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I thought UIControlEventTouchCancel is triggered when I tap on a button and then drag out of it. But I'm doing exactly that and my event handler is never called.

I have a class that inherits from UIControl and I'm doing this in the init:

```
[self addTarget:self action:@selector(onTouchCancel)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

How do I trigger the cancel event?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "UIControlEventTouchUpOutside" if you want an event when the finger is outside the bounds of the control.

Comment: to trigger that I would have to lift my finger. Is there no way to detect a dragExit as soon as it actually exits? I tried UIControlEventDragExit but that somehow is triggered too late.

Comment: ok, maybe I just have to live with it. It seems that these events just can't be detected any faster.